# Icons not getting while we are converting JS file to TS file in React marterial-table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using a `react.js` project and I installed material-ui's table in the `table.js`, it's working fine, but then,  if I'm converting `.ts` files it's not getting icons for previous and next pages.

So, If I need to convert `.js` files to `.ts` files or `.tsx` files we have to get the UI, but here not getting please tell me about the thing of issue.

So I tagged the issue of screenshot. I want like this

[image]

But I am getting like this

[image]

Comment: care to share your webpack config?

Comment: yes its getting js or jsx files not coming into.... ts ot .tsx files